# I can not get the multiplication tables between two values recursively 5-8=tables of 6 nd 7

Tags: java, recursion

i just know how to get the multiplication table of one number.
i have tryied put another number in method argument but nothing.

```
input
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    table(2,10);
    }

    public static void table(int num,int a) {
            if(a>=0) {
                table(num,a-1);
                System.out.println(num+" x "+a+" = "+num*a);
            }
    }

output
2 x 0 = 0
2 x 1 = 2
2 x 2 = 4
2 x 3 = 6
2 x 4 = 8
2 x 5 = 10
2 x 6 = 12
2 x 7 = 14
2 x 8 = 16
2 x 9 = 18
2 x 10 = 20
```

Comment: Whats expected output?

Comment: On your condition, if a>0, you could call table again with `num-1`, 10. You'll need to keep track of your limits if you don't want to reset all the way to 10.

Comment: for values of 5 and 8 output would be multiplication tables of 6 and 7

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you must use recursive,but maybe you expected is next.

```
public static void table(int num,int a) {
                if(a >= 0 && num <= a) {
                    for(int i = 0;i <= a;i++){
                      System.out.println(num+" x "+i+" = "+num*a);
                    }
                    if(num<a){
                       table(num+1,a);
                    }                     
                }
        }
```